# django-mptt-comments app error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-apps, django-comments

I am trying to use `django-mptt-comments` app on my django project  however I'm running into problems when I try posting a comment.

I get the error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'level'`

Here is the traceback: https://gist.github.com/1481179

You will notice in the traceback that the error occurs in the appp's form.py at line 93. Here is what the code looks like: https://gist.github.com/1481191

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this problem and how I could go about fixing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not usingdjango-mptt-comments but I saw something a bit suspicious in the stacktrace, it looks like the form get initialized in django/contrib/comments/forms.py which it sounds a bit weird.

Maybe you have the django.contrib.comments app installed and it interacts somehow ?